# How does OracleRefereceCursor get data from database?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, odp.net

Let's say I have a stored procedure in Oracle db which has a ref cursor output parameter.

From .Net using ODP.Net I am trying to get the data from the DB as below (I have taken this from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-refcursors-092375.html)

```
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("otn_ref_cursor.get_emp_info", con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  // create parameter object for the cursor
  OracleParameter p_refcursor = new OracleParameter();

  // this is vital to set when using ref cursors
  p_refcursor.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;

  // this is a function return value so we must indicate that fact
  p_refcursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

  // add the parameter to the collection
  cmd.Parameters.Add(p_refcursor);

  // create a data adapter to use with the data set
  OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

  // create the data set
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();

  // fill the data set
  da.Fill(ds);
```

How does the dataset fill the records? Does it make one round-trip to database server to get one record at a time?

Is it the same as

```
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   //Do Something 
}
```

I think the approach of using DataReader will make one round-trip per each row to db, is my understanding correct?

Comment: The amount of data fetched in each roundtrip to the database is controlled by the Fetchsize which is a certain number of bytes. I forget the default size. You can control this by setting FetchSize to a multiple of Rowsize. ODP.NET will cache the data until it needs to fetch more.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianShay , that addresses my concern of making too many round trips to db to fetch the data.

Comment: Great. I went ahead and added it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of data fetched in each roundtrip to the database is controlled by the Fetchsize which is a certain number of bytes. I forget the default size. You can control this by setting FetchSize to a multiple of Rowsize. ODP.NET will cache the data until it needs to fetch more.